# How does Pass Transistor Logic work?

Tags: transistors, mosfet, nmos

Why the voltage at Source terminal in MOST device in pass transistor logic is given by: Min(Vgs-Vt,Vdd). How we arrive at this expression.

[image]

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: @JImDearden My question is why the voltage is given by that expression only. How that expression is coming.

Comment: When you refer to "MOST" are you talking about the standard for digital communications for automotive electronics?

Answer (score 3):

A PMOS passes a perfect 1, but a degraded 0.

An NMOS passes a perfect 0, but a degraded 1.

This comes because in pass transistor logic the source and drain nodes are not fixed.  The source and drain switch whenever the transistor is either charging or discharging the load capacitance.

So, when the NMOS is charging up the load capacitance, the source is the input signal and the drain is the output signal.  In this situation the drain cannot charge up past Vgs - Vth because at that point the transistor turns off (Vgs is not greater than Vth).

But, whenever the NMOS is discharging the load capacitance, the source is the load and the drain is the input (which is at ground).  In this case the Vgs is always greater than Vth (since the input is at ground).  And the cap discharges all the way to 0V.

PMOS work in a similar way, but opposite of the NMOS (passing a solid '1' but a degraded '0').

For this reason PMOS and NMOS are combined into "transmission gates" which pass both a solid '0' and '1' (the selects are inverted).

[image: transmissino gates]